# Laravel - Pass a function parameter to a DB method

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I have a function that is taking an id as a param, and updates the db using the DB method. however, when i run the code, the variable is not being passed to the method. to test, i replaced $id with an integer and it worked, so i think the DB method can not access the variable from the parameter

```
public function disable($id)
{

    // Update the user status to 0 from 1
    DB::table('employees')->where('id', $id)->update(['status' => 0]);
    return redirect('/employee')->with('error', 'User is disabled, all related accounts are now shutdown!...');
}
```

Update:
Forgot to mention that i have already checked, and the param comes inside the function OK, i can return the id outside of the method

SOLUTION
As shown in the comment, the varDump was returning "id=9" where i need "9", i noticed in the form piece of my code, there was an extra "id=" before the id which caused a malfunction.

Comment: post the example of when when you call the method with a non-integer parameter

Comment: Is this function called in the request ?

Comment: i think your `$id` parameter is a string, so mysql is failed to match the id, convert it in an integer as `$id=(int)$id;`, then try

Comment: yes it's called in the request

Comment: call `dd($id);` in this function to check if `$id` is passed true

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR I added $id= (int)$id; to convert, but didn't work either

Comment: @Beaumind yes i have tried that before, i should have mentioned.

Comment: @user1622997 just var_dump($id), to check what you are getting in $id

Comment: what `dd($id)` returns?

Comment: @Beaumind the id that was passed to the function (i.e "id=9" )

Comment: @Beaumind I see what's going on the content of the var is literally "id=9" NOT "9" so DB is building { where('id', $request->id=9) } which doesn't return anything!

Comment: So you are passing the variable wrongly. I guessed that

Comment: in my FORM i was adding the 'id=' to my param, I kept getting confused with the varDump result. thanks again for your help guys. All good!

Answer (score 1):

Use function as `disable(Request $request)` and get id as `$request->id`

```
public function disable(Request $request)
{
    // Update the user status to 0 from 1
    DB::table('employees')->where('id', $request->id)->update(['status' => 0]);
    return redirect('/employee')->with('error', 'User is disabled, all related accounts are now shutdown!...');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't make a difference!. the weird thing is I can replace the $id with a static number from the DB and run, which updates. so I know the method is good, also, I can echo the $id after the method has run, so i know the $id is coming in too, but they don't talk to each other!

Comment: what you are getting in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` ?